# Does the assignment operator overwrite argument reference in Python functions?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

The goal is to update a list by function call which takes two arguments, one being the list to be modified.
In the following example, `j` is the list to be modified by function `f()`:

```
import numpy as np

j = np.log(np.array([[0.3],[0.4]]))
k = np.log(np.array([[0.1],[0.3]]))

def f(a,b):
    a = np.exp(a) - np.exp(b)

f(j,k)

print(j)
```

The expected solution was:

```
[[ 0.2]
 [ 0.1]]
```

However, it produces :

```
[[-1.2039728 ]
 [-0.91629073]]
```

which is the original value of `j`. That is, `j` was never modified.

But if the `+=` is used instead with the `-a` trick,

```
def f(a,b):
    a += -a + np.exp(a) - np.exp(b)
```

then the output is the expected solution.

Hence, the question: does the assignment operator overwrite argument reference in Python functions?
Is there an explanation for why `j`'s behavior changes if `=` or `+=` is used?

Comment: Yes. `a = <whatever>` *never directly modifies `a`, it merely changes the object that the variable `a` is referencing*. Augmented assignment *may* change an object in-place, which happens to be true for `numpy` arrays, but not, for example, with `int` objects (since they are immutable).  Please read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Also, python does not support pass-by-reference semantics at all.